# how does the program know which picture is in the picture box as it is a variable?

Tags: vb.net

I'm writing a code for a game, it's a game where you see random a picture of a city and then you have to write in a textbox what it's called.

This is what I have now:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.BackColor = Color.Yellow

    'achtergrond kleur is geel'


End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim stad As Integer
    Randomize()
    stad = Int(Rnd() * 10) + 1

    If stad = 1 Then PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.amsterdam
    If stad = 2 Then PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.berlijn
    If stad = 3 Then PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.moskou
    If stad = 4 Then PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.neworleans
    If stad = 5 Then PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.newyork
    If stad = 6 Then PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.parijs
    If stad = 7 Then PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.rome
    If stad = 8 Then PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.sanfransisco
    If stad = 9 Then PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.shanghai
    If stad = 10 Then PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.tokio

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim name As String
    name = TextBox1.Text

    If PictureBox1.Image Is My.Resources.amsterdam And name = "amsterdam" Then MsgBox("Dit antwoord is goed voor 1 punt")
    If PictureBox1.Image Is My.Resources.berlijn And name = "berlijn" Then MsgBox("Dit antwoord is goed voor 1 punt")
    If PictureBox1.Image Is My.Resources.moskou And name = "moskou" Then MsgBox("Dit antwoord is goed voor 1 punt")
    If PictureBox1.Image Is My.Resources.neworleans And name = "new orleans" Then MsgBox("Dit antwoord is goed voor 1 punt")
    If PictureBox1.Image Is My.Resources.newyork And name = "newyork" Then MsgBox("Dit antwoord is goed voor 1 punt")
    If PictureBox1.Image Is My.Resources.parijs And name = "parijs" Then MsgBox("Dit antwoord is goed voor 1 punt")
    If PictureBox1.Image Is My.Resources.rome And name = "rome" Then MsgBox("Dit antwoord is goed voor 1 punt")
    If PictureBox1.Image Is My.Resources.sanfransisco And name = "san fransisco" Then MsgBox("Dit antwoord is goed voor 1 punt")
    If PictureBox1.Image Is My.Resources.tokio And name = "tokio" Then MsgBox("Dit antwoord is goed voor 1 punt")
    If PictureBox1.Image Is My.Resources.shanghai And name = "shanghai" Then MsgBox("Dit antwoord is goed voor 1 punt")

    If name = "" Then MsgBox("U heeft nog niks ingevuld, vul de juiste stad in a.u.b.")

End Sub
```

The problem is the program doesn't know what picture is in the picturebox, so how let I know which picture is in the picture box?

Comment: Declare `stad` outside the click event and it will still hold the index later when you need it elsewhere or store the name to the picturebox Tag property when you set the image.

Comment: The My.Resources.something property creates a *new* object every time you use it.  You will never get a match on the PictureBox1.Image property.  You also leak the bitmap object profusely, your program isn't likely to going to run for very long.  You must create variables that store the image objects so you use My.Resources.something only *once*.  Initialize the variables in your form constructor (Sub New).  Make it pretty by using a `Dictionary(Of City, Image)` where City is an enum.

Answer (score 0):

Try below. Please add other if conditions for multiple picture box images in `Button1_Click`.

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim stad As Integer
        Randomize()
        stad = Int(Rnd() * 10) + 1

        If stad = 1 Then
            PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.amsterdam
            PictureBox1.Tag = "amsterdam"
        ElseIf stad = 2 Then
            PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.berlijn
            PictureBox1.Tag = "berlijn"
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim name As String
        name = TextBox1.Text

        If name = "" Then
            MsgBox("U heeft nog niks ingevuld, vul de juiste stad in a.u.b.")
        ElseIf TextBox1.Text.Trim = PictureBox1.Tag Then
            MsgBox("Dit antwoord is goed voor 1 punt")
        End If

    End Sub
```